# Sort rails results by price

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wanting to sort this:

```
  @results = Table.where(merchant_deep_link: results)
```

via search_price (a column that sits inside the `Table` table)

```
  @results = Table.where(merchant_deep_link: results).order(:search_price)
```

However in my view i have this:

```
<%= @results.first.search_price %>
```

Which didn't return a low price, It returned a random price in the middle (low price being 69.00 and it returned 103.00)

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the query produced by ActiveRecord?

Comment: in addition to @Rashmirathi question. Use `Table.where(merchant_deep_link: results).order(:search_price).to_sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a different order set previously. Instead of `order`, use `reorder`: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-reorder

```
@results = Table.where(merchant_deep_link: results).reorder(:search_price)
```